# Design pattern for filtering objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a List of objects which will be filtered.

This filtering will consist of at least 3 rules.

So for example :

```
public class Filtering {

List<MyObject> myObjectList;

List<MyObject> filterStep1(List<MyObject> myObjectList){

    for(Myobject myobj : myObjectList){
        if(isCriteriaSatisified){
            continue
        }
        else {
            removeThisObjectFromList
        }
    }
}


List<MyObject> filterStep2(List<MyObject> myObjectList){

    for(Myobject myobj : myObjectList){
        if(isCriteriaSatisified){
            continue
        }
        else {
            removeThisObjectFromList
        }
    }
}

}
```

I like this approach as it is simple, self contained and can see very easily what is trying to be achieved.

But perhaps there is a design pattern I should be using instead ?

The "Chain of Responsibility" pattern is something I'm considering where filterStep1 & filterStep2 in above code would be refactored into a seperate hander.

Comment: You can consider the Java8's Stream API, which provides great filtering options for Collection objects.

Comment: This question would be much better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just one remark : you are modifying the original lists. What I call filtering would be to generate a new list containing only valid elements without modifying original list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the "pipes and filters" pattern, and while your implementation is okay, it's better not to hardcode the filtering logic in methods. Instead, write a `Predicate<MyObject>` for each of your boolean conditions (either the one built into Java 8 or the one from Guava). This is much easier to test and can easily be applied to existing clean APIs, such as the Streams API or Guava's collection views.

Comment: I agree using functions for filtering is much cleaner but I cannot use the Java8 API. So I will use my suggested option in question. Thanks

Comment: @blue-sky Look at Guava as an option for implementing the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

One option using Java 8 streams:

```
myObjects.stream().filter( this::isCriteriaSatisified ).filter( this::anotherCriteria )
```

Assuming you have a method `boolean isCriteriaSatisified(myObj)` in your class. You can then collect that stream into another List.